# Show random images with their names from an array. (SwiftUI)

Tags: arrays, swift, image, swiftui, swift5

New to swiftUI, and I need to show the images and their names randomly by action of a button. How should I call the pictures' array to show a random picture each time user tap on the button  in the contentView file ?

this is the array of pictures that I want to show them randomly in contentView(pictures placed in Assets folder):

```
struct aPicture: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var imageName: String
}


let pictures = [
    aPicture(id: 0, name: "1", imageName: "1"),
    aPicture(id: 1, name: "2", imageName: "2"),
    aPicture(id: 2, name: "3", imageName: "3"),
    aPicture(id: 3, name: "4", imageName: "4"),
    aPicture(id: 4, name: "5", imageName: "5"),
    aPicture(id: 5, name: "6", imageName: "6"),
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Would you show code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
 struct ContentView: View {

    struct aPicture: Identifiable {
        var id: Int
        var name: String
        var imageName: String
    }

    @State var random : Int = 0


    let pictures = [
        aPicture(id: 0, name: "1", imageName: "1"),
        aPicture(id: 1, name: "2", imageName: "2"),
        aPicture(id: 2, name: "3", imageName: "3"),
        aPicture(id: 3, name: "4", imageName: "4"),
        aPicture(id: 4, name: "5", imageName: "5"),
        aPicture(id: 5, name: "6", imageName: "6"),
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text(pictures[self.random].name)
                    .background(Color.white)
                Spacer()
                Button("Next image") {
                    self.random = Int.random(in: 0..<self.pictures.count)
                }
                Spacer()
            }

            Image(pictures[self.random].imageName)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I show the "name" attribute of "aPicture" in a Text box, which randomly selected by your "random" code ?

Comment: i updated the answer which shows now the name of the picture too.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you different approach.
1) you can generate random element directly

```
let picture = pictures.randomElement() ?? default_if_empty_collection
```

2) user would like to see different picture after tap, which could not be true. Less pictures in your "store", more likely randomly you generate the same picture (which could looks like "nothing happens on tap")

next snippet shows how to solve this. On every tap the user see different picture, even though there are just tree pictures in our collection.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var img  = Image(systemName: "questionmark.square.fill")
    let imgs = [Image(systemName: "trash"),
                Image(systemName: "trash.fill"),
                Image(systemName: "trash.slash"),

    ]

    var body: some View {
        img
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .onTapGesture {
                var tmp: Image
                repeat {
                    tmp = self.imgs.randomElement() ?? self.img
                } while tmp == self.img
                self.img = tmp
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is cool. But I had to randomly select an image with various attributes attached with it(such as name, date, location, etc.)  and then show them in a stack view.

Comment: no trouble, you can. you have some collection, you can randomly get element from it and check if it differs from the current ...